# Mapstruct - map property to property of object in a List

Tags: java, mapstruct

Hello I have the following class:

```
public class BookWriteModel {
    List<PageWriteModel> pages;
}

public class Book {
    List<Page> pages;
}

public class PageWriteModel {
    Long pageNumber;
}

public class Page {
    Long pageNumber;
    Long userId;
}

public class User {
    Long userId;
}
```

My mapper as of now is something like this:

```
@Mapper( componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE )
public interface BookMapper {
    Book map(BookWriteModel bookWriteModel, User user);
}
```

What is the simpler way to map the `userId` to the `userId` on the Page?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `==` or even `.equals()`?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1: [@AfterMapping](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after) method**

```java
@Mapper( componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE )
public interface BookMapper {
    BookMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(BookMapper.class);

    Book map(BookWriteModel bookWriteModel, User user);

    @AfterMapping
    default void afterMap(@MappingTarget Book book, User user) {
        if (user != null) {
            for (Page page : book.pages) {
                page.userId = user.userId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Generated code:

```java
@Component
public class BookMapperImpl implements BookMapper {
    @Override
    public Book map(BookWriteModel bookWriteModel, User user) {
        if ( bookWriteModel == null && user == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Book book = new Book();
        if ( bookWriteModel != null ) {
            book.pages = pageWriteModelListToPageList( bookWriteModel.pages );
        }
        afterMap( book, user );
        return book;
    }

    protected Page pageWriteModelToPage(PageWriteModel pageWriteModel) {
        if ( pageWriteModel == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Page page = new Page();
        page.pageNumber = pageWriteModel.pageNumber;
        return page;
    }

    protected List<Page> pageWriteModelListToPageList(List<PageWriteModel> list) {
        if ( list == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        List<Page> list1 = new ArrayList<Page>( list.size() );
        for ( PageWriteModel pageWriteModel : list ) {
            list1.add( pageWriteModelToPage( pageWriteModel ) );
        }
        return list1;
    }
}
```

**Solution 2: using [@Context](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#passing-context) togather [@ObjectFactory](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#object-factories)**

```java
@Mapper( componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE )
public interface BookMapper {
    BookMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(BookMapper.class);

    Book map(BookWriteModel bookWriteModel, @Context User user);

    @ObjectFactory
    default Page create(@Context User user) {
        Page page = new Page();
        if (user != null) {
            page.userId = user.userId;
        }
        return page;
    }
}
```

Generated code:

```java
@Component
public class BookMapperImpl implements BookMapper {
    @Override
    public Book map(BookWriteModel bookWriteModel, User user) {
        if ( bookWriteModel == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Book book = new Book();
        book.pages = pageWriteModelListToPageList( bookWriteModel.pages, user );
        return book;
    }

    protected Page pageWriteModelToPage(PageWriteModel pageWriteModel, User user) {
        if ( pageWriteModel == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Page page = create( user );
        page.pageNumber = pageWriteModel.pageNumber;
        return page;
    }

    protected List<Page> pageWriteModelListToPageList(List<PageWriteModel> list, User user) {
        if ( list == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        List<Page> list1 = new ArrayList<Page>( list.size() );
        for ( PageWriteModel pageWriteModel : list ) {
            list1.add( pageWriteModelToPage( pageWriteModel, user ) );
        }
        return list1;
    }
}
```

**Solution 3: using [@Context](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#passing-context) togather [@ObjectFactory](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#object-factories) and additional mapping method**

```java
@Mapper( componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface BookMapper {
    BookMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(BookMapper.class);

    Book map(BookWriteModel bookWriteModel, @Context User user);
    
    Page map(User user);

    @ObjectFactory
    default Page create(@Context User user) {
        Page page = map(user);
        return page == null ? new Page() : page;
    }
}
```

Generated code:

```java
@Component
public class BookMapperImpl implements BookMapper {
    @Override
    public Book map(BookWriteModel bookWriteModel, User user) {
        if ( bookWriteModel == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Book book = new Book();
        book.pages = pageWriteModelListToPageList( bookWriteModel.pages, user );
        return book;
    }

    @Override
    public Page map(User user) {
        if ( user == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Page page = new Page();
        page.userId = user.userId;
        return page;
    }

    protected Page pageWriteModelToPage(PageWriteModel pageWriteModel, User user) {
        if ( pageWriteModel == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Page page = create( user );
        page.pageNumber = pageWriteModel.pageNumber;
        return page;
    }

    protected List<Page> pageWriteModelListToPageList(List<PageWriteModel> list, User user) {
        if ( list == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        List<Page> list1 = new ArrayList<Page>( list.size() );
        for ( PageWriteModel pageWriteModel : list ) {
            list1.add( pageWriteModelToPage( pageWriteModel, user ) );
        }
        return list1;
    }
}
```

**Solution 4: [@Context](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#passing-context) method as proxy to mapping method**

```java
@Mapper( componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface BookMapper {
    BookMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(BookMapper.class);

    Book map(BookWriteModel bookWriteModel, @Context User user);

    Page map(PageWriteModel pageWriteModel, User user);

    default Page mapContext(PageWriteModel pageWriteModel, @Context User user) {
        return map(pageWriteModel, user);
    }
}
```

Generated code:

```java
@Component
public class BookMapperImpl implements BookMapper {

    @Override
    public Book map(BookWriteModel bookWriteModel, User user) {
        if ( bookWriteModel == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Book book = new Book();

        book.pages = pageWriteModelListToPageList( bookWriteModel.pages, user );

        return book;
    }

    @Override
    public Page map(PageWriteModel pageWriteModel, User user) {
        if ( pageWriteModel == null && user == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Page page = new Page();

        if ( pageWriteModel != null ) {
            page.pageNumber = pageWriteModel.pageNumber;
        }
        if ( user != null ) {
            page.userId = user.userId;
        }
        return page;
    }

    protected List<Page> pageWriteModelListToPageList(List<PageWriteModel> list, User user) {
        if ( list == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        List<Page> list1 = new ArrayList<Page>( list.size() );
        for ( PageWriteModel pageWriteModel : list ) {
            list1.add( mapContext( pageWriteModel, user ) );
        }
        return list1;
    }
}
```

I think, **Solution 4** is clear and preferable.

Comment: The main idea of Solution 4 use the default method with context which will call mapping method. `Context` there is only to pass parameter to default method. `Context` is not using in mapping at all. It is working well with  1.5.1.Final  and  1.4.2.Final. In case you have problems with `Context` use simple  Solution 1.